# MonoTouch memory issue with Threading / Timers

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am having an issue with MonoTouch where UIViewControllers are remaining in-memory forever, even after they have been popped from the navigation stack.

I have a UINavigationController which contains a UIViewController with a button. Clicking the button pushes a custom UIViewController called ThreadingViewController onto the navigation stack.

The ThreadingViewController uses a NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer and a Thread to update the text of a label every one second.

When the user clicks "back" to pop back to the root view, the Mono Profiler says that my ThreadingViewController still exists in memory. The Profiler tells me it has something to do with NSAction and/or ThreadStart which has a reference to the ThreadingViewController, keeping it alive. I can see this by checking the "inverse references" checkbox in the profiler.

This means that if the user clicks backwards and forwards 100 times between the root ViewController and the custom ThreadingViewController, there will be 100 instances of this ViewController in memory. It isn't being garbage collected.

In ViewDidDisappear I have tried aborting the thread, setting it to null, to no avail.

What do I need to do to get this ThreadingViewController to be properly cleaned up / GC'ed by MonoTouch?

Here is the full (C# only) source code to reproduce the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Threading;

namespace MemoryTests
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        private UIWindow window;
        private UINavigationController rootNavigationController;
        private RootScreen rootScreen;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            rootScreen = new RootScreen();
            rootNavigationController = new UINavigationController(rootScreen);
            window.RootViewController = rootNavigationController;

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class RootScreen : UIViewController
    {
        private UIButton button;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            this.Title = "Root Screen";

            // Add a button
            button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            button.SetTitle("Click me", UIControlState.Normal);
            button.Frame = new RectangleF(100, 100, 120, 44);
            this.View.Add(button);
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            button.TouchUpInside += PushThreadingViewController;
        }

        public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);

            button.TouchUpInside -= PushThreadingViewController;
        }

        private void PushThreadingViewController(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var threadingViewController = new ThreadingViewController();
            NavigationController.PushViewController(threadingViewController, true);
        }
    }

    public class ThreadingViewController : UIViewController
    {
        private UILabel label;
        private NSTimer timer;
        private int counter;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            this.Title = "Threading Screen";

            // Add a label
            label = new UILabel();
            label.Frame = new RectangleF(0f, 200f, 320f, 44f);
            label.Text = "Count: 0";
            this.View.Add(label);

            // Start a timer
            var timerThread = new Thread(StartTimer as ThreadStart);
            timerThread.Start();
        }

        public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);

            timer.Dispose();
            timer = null;
            // Do I need to clean up more Threading things here?
        }

        [Export("StartTimer")]
        private void StartTimer()
        {
            using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
            {
                timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(1d, TimerTicked);
                NSRunLoop.Current.Run();
            }
        }

        private void TimerTicked()
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                label.Text = "Count: " + counter;
                counter++;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the profiler telling me that we have 3 instances of ThreadingViewController in memory:

[image]

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
timer.Dispose();
```

Try changing it to:

```
timer.Invalidate();
```

`NSTimer` is the only thing here that uses an `NSAction`.
Also, I don't think this is very helpful:

```
var timerThread = new Thread(StartTimer as ThreadStart);
timerThread.Start();
```

Reasons:

1. It's not a background thread. Not sure how foreground .NET threads behave on iOS. My guess is, it never finishes.
2. You don't need to have a separate thread live all the time, within from you are starting the NSTimer. NSTimers are light, bulletproof and provide all the options you need. They work great even if you are starting them on the UI thread.
   (Please ignore #2 above if you have another reason you are doing it this way, which is not directly visible from your code. But, nothing else comes to mind).

PS: I haven't tested your code above. But I'm 100% sure that you must `Invalidate()` `NSTimers` so that they stop running, when you no longer need them.

Comment: Calling timer.Invalidate() didn't help. Also, when I removed the two lines of code you suggested, which started off the timer in a thread, and instead just started off the timer directly by calling StartTimer(), the whole thing broke: the UI just froze. Other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, did you also remove NSRunLoop.Current.Run(); ? It blocks the thread. And of course, the InvokeOnMainThread in TimerTicked will also need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you connect a click handler such as:

button.TouchUpInside += PushThreadingViewController;

You must also disconnect it.  I would suggest moving the line of code above to the ViewDidAppear override, and adding the line of code below to the ViewDidDisappear override:

button.TouchUpInside -= PushThreadingViewController;

I would also recommend that you check to see if threadingViewController is null and only creating a new instance if it is, before pushing it onto the navigation stack. That way it will use the same one each time if it hasn't been garbage collected yet.

Comment: I have updated the code sample so it subscribes and unsubscribes to the button click event when the view appears and disappears. It does not fix the problem. I was also under the impression that reusing the same UIViewController is bad practice. In reality I want to pass data to the UIViewController each time, so I want a new UIViewController, not an old one with old state left lying around.

Comment: I wasn't aware that reusing a UIViewController is bad practice, though I would be curious to know why. You can pass data to the threadingViewController each time, as you have a reference to it in your rootViewController. That reference from your rootViewController may actually be what is preventing the threadingViewController from being garbage collected. Also, you can override the dispose method, which is where you should be disposing of your objects.

Comment: Try and run my sample code and reproduce the problem. Comment-out the two lines of code below the comment "Start a timer". The ThreadingViewController is cleaned up by the GC. With threading, it isn't. So whether we create that variable on the fly or have an instance variable appears to be of no consequence...

Comment: Instead of just using: "var timerThread = new Thread(StartTimer as ThreadStart);", create a private field in your threadingViewController for timerThread, so you can dispose of it as well.

Comment: Tried. Doesn't help. I also extracted "StartTimer as ThreadStart" into a private field and set that to null too. Didn't help either...

Comment: @AlexYork: Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with ViewDidDisappear. This method may called at any time your View-Controller yields control to another View-Controller (calling PresentViewController, invoking the sharing UI, display an iAd etc). If you only want to react when your View-Controller is removed from the navigation stack, I'd recommend this:

```
public override void DidMoveToParentViewController(UIViewController parent)
{
  base.DidMoveToParentViewController(parent);

  if(parent == null)
    Cleanup();
}
```

Try invoking **ReleaseOutlets**() (generated from the Xamarin Studio XIB processor) from within your **Cleanup**() method in addition to unwiring the touch event handler improves the situation.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the issue using my sample code, implement your suggestions, and solve the problem...?

Comment: I am aware that this isn't DoMyHomework.com. But you can see from my sample code that there is no XIB's involved. So I don't know how ReleaseOutlets() could possibly help. I am also quite sure that there is no problem with ViewDidDisappear(). The issue is with Threading. Commenting out the two lines of code that starts the Thread fixes the problem. With Threading back in, the memory build-up issue arises again...